# Testing actual rating booster using Askingpoint SDK

Tags: ios, rate

I integrated Askingpoint framework and prompted testing rating booster, which is working fine, but i want to check the actual booster. I am not getting actual booster even all conditions met.

I called

```
[APManager startup:@"APP_KEY"];
```

in appdelegate to startup Askingpoint and followed all guidelines given in document.

How can I test the actual rating booster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by reading documentation of sdk carefully, As i integrated AskingPoint SDK by calling method

```
[APManager startup:@"APP_KEY"];
```

Every thing was ok there but problem is only of rules mismatching, because i mentioned there more than conditions in a rule, so all the conditions mentioned in rule must be matched

Answer (score 0):

Hi Im an AskingPoint founder. You can easily test any AskingPoint feature, including Ratings Booster using its associated Test feature. It's all documented in the [AskingPoint Support Pages](https://www.askingpoint.com/support_site) (site usage sections). But in brief you do it like so:

1. First Add a test device(s) to your account, including simulators.
2. Then select the App on your Dashboard you want to test Ratings Booster in.
3. Fire test, and run the App.
4. Using this method of Testing overrides ALL Rules and Conditions and it will *always* show as often as you fire it.

It is translated into all iOS languages but if you want to see a specific one, put the device into that language and fire the test.